# Can't identify frame by URL

Tags: vbscript, automation, automated-tests, qtp

I am getting the URL and HTML ID of the frame using the `GetRoProperty` method and using the same values to identify the object via descriptive programming.

QTP is identifying the object using HTML ID, but when it uses URL for identifying its shows

> Cannot identify the object "[ Frame ]" (of class Frame). Verify that
>   this object's properties match an object currently displayed in your
>   application.
>
> Line (24): "print Browser("SAP - [Search: Accounts]").Window("Partner Selection Document").Page("Partner Selection Document").Frame("url:="&rourl).GetROProperty("html id")".

In OR, QTP identifies the frame using URL alone without any other properties.

Following are the lines of code involved:

```
rourl=Browser("SAP - [Search: Accounts]").Window("Partner Selection Document").Page("Partner Selection Document").Frame("Frame").GetROProperty("url")

print rourl
roid=Browser("SAP - [Search: Accounts]").Window("Partner Selection Document").Page("Partner Selection Document").Frame("Frame").GetROProperty("html id")
print roid

print Browser("SAP - [Search: Accounts]").Window("Partner Selection Document").Page("Partner Selection Document").Frame("html id:="&roid).GetROProperty("html id")
'prints html id
print Browser("SAP - [Search: Accounts]").Window("Partner Selection Document").Page("Partner Selection Document").Frame("url:="&rourl).GetROProperty("html id")
'shows error message
```

url of frame is `http://part1.part2.part3.part4.com:8082/sap(bD1FTiZjPTUwMCZpPTEmZT1WRVZUVkY5Rk1rVkJWVlJQTVRJM01USmZWY3gxMlR4aUNVRGhBSUFBQ2hvd2NnJTNkJTNk)/bc/bsp/sap/crm_ui_frame/bspwdapplication.do?popup-name=_POPUP0001&wcf-request-ticket=929D13152F6D62ACF1AB51BD8BDC2819`

I have modified the url as

`http://part1\.part2\.part3\.part4\.com:8082/sap\(bD1FTiZjPTUwMCZpPTEmZT1WRVZUVkY5Rk1rVkJWVlJQTVRJM01USmZWY3gxMlR4aUNVRGhBSUFBQ2hvd2NnJTNkJTNk\)/bc/bsp/sap/crm_ui_frame/bspwdapplication\.do\?popup-name=_POPUP0001&wcf-request-ticket=929D13152F6D62ACF1AB51BD8BDC2819`

But still is not identifying.

```
rourl="http://part1\.part2\.part3\.part4\.com:8082/sap\(bD1FTiZjPTUwMCZpPTEmZT1WRVZUVkY5Rk1rVkJWVlJQTVRJM01USmZWY3gxMlR4aUNVRGhBSUFBQ2hvd2NnJTNkJTNk\)/bc/bsp/sap/crm_ui_frame/bspwdapplication\.do\?popup-name=_POPUP0001&wcf-request-ticket=929D13152F6D62ACF1AB51BD8BDC2819"
Browser("SAP - [Search: Accounts]").Window("Select Transaction Type").Page("Select Transaction Type").Frame("url:="&rourl).GetROProperty("html id")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably due to the fact that descriptive programming uses regular expressions and the object repository by default does not use regular expressions.

Your URL may contain special characters that have a different meaning when viewed as a regular expression. 
The most obvious regex special characters that tend to appear in URLs are `.` and `?`. I think that you have a problem with `?` (since `.` matches `"."` but it can cause ambiguities.

Try this:

```
Function EscapeRegex(str)
    str = Replace(str, "?", "\?")
    str = Replace(str, ".", "\.")
    EscapeRegex = str   
End Function

print Browser("SAP - [Search: Accounts]").Window("Partner Selection Document").Page("Partner Selection Document").Frame("html id:="& EscapeRegex(roid)).GetROProperty("html id")
```

If this doesn't solve your problem please add special characters to the `EscapeRegex` function, if you still can't get it to work please post a sample URL that causes this problem.

For reference here's a (partial?) list of special regular expression characters:
`[]*.?+^$()|{}\` (here's [how it's done in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript)).

Comment: I have changed the url to escape special characters.Still I am getting the same error.Please got through the updated question for more details.

Comment: @rijinrv perhaps try escaping the forward slashes too `\/` otherwise I don't know :(

Comment: Its working now ..Thanks for the reply..I didn't escape the forward slashes ..but still its working..

Comment: @rijinrv, yeah escaping the slashes was clutching at straws (it shouldn't work) I wonder what was wrong before...